# phpunit --debug still displays only dots

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to see which test is currently executed during a phpunit run.

I use the `--debug` param but still only get dots:

```
$ phpunit --debug 
PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/foo/bar/phpunit.xml

..S.......I..
```

contents of `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
     bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     cacheTokens="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     forceCoversAnnotation="false"
     mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
     printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnError="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     stopOnIncomplete="false"
     stopOnSkipped="false"
     testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"
     strict="false"
     verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="foo Tests">
        <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="./clover.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Aren't you looking for `--verbose` instead?

Comment: You'd want to rephrase the question, then, as it's unclear what you want. (The list of switches is here, btw: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/textui.html)

Comment: @Denis, verbose is already true in his phpunit.xml

Comment: In PHPUNIT 4.8.30 (and up, presumably), --debug works for this.

Comment: I would have phrased this "How do I stop the default dot progress output when running PHPUnit test?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it by **removing** this:

```
printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
```

from the options on the base  tag in the phpunit.xml config file.

Comment: For clarification, When I set this in my PHPUnit configuration file, this prevents the default dot progress and uses only the logging specified in the configuration file.

Answer (score 96):

You want to be using [--testdox](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/textui.html#testdox)

> phpunit --testdox

Comment: The problem with `--testdox` (at least in my experience...) is that it doesn't display the errors at the bottom of the test run like the other ones, so you have to scan up and look for empty `[  ]`s

Comment: @SeanJA And if you have skipped tests, they are also displayed as empty `[ ]` so using `--testdox` it will be impossible to know which tests failed.

Answer (score 24):

(Answering the question of "how to see which test is currently running")

As you've noticed --debug and --verbose are of little help. (I use --verbose most of the time, but because it tells me more information when things go wrong, and isn't really very verbose the rest of the time.)

Here was my first try:

```
phpunit --verbose --tap
```

I tried it out on a test suite that has some slow tests. It worked beautifully until test 21, then nothing, then a few minutes later tests 22 to 598 appeared in one go. I suspect output buffering. Here is a variation that does not have this problem, but requires two terminal windows open:

```
phpunit --verbose --log-tap tap.log
```

Then in another window:

```
tail -f tap.log
```

Actually it doesn't tell you exactly what you want, because it only reports which function it *was* working on. So, when you get a delay you have to wait for the test to finish to discover which is the slow test.

To get more control consider [writing your own test listener](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener).

Comment: The point is that on other systems `--debug` used to work well ... But those was Magento/EcomDev_PHPUnit, no I am on Symfony2 - maybe it came not directly from PHPUnit? no clue ...

Comment: @Darren, Wouldn't "delayed output" be considered  to be a bug?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't know. Output buffering is probably there to enable some important phpunit feature.   I think if you write your own test listener class then there should be no delay (but if there was a delay on the `startTest` hook then that would count as a bug).

Comment: This gives a `Unknown option "--tap"` error in `v9.5`

Answer (score 9):

The best solution I find was to add logging section to your phpunit.xml file

```
<logging>
    <log type="testdox-text" target="php://stdout"/>
</logging>
```